# LINQ sorting anonymous types?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How do I do sorting when generating anonymous types in linq to sql?

Ex:

```
from e in linq0
order by User descending /* ??? */
select new
{
   Id = e.Id,
   CommentText = e.CommentText,
   UserId = e.UserId,
   User = (e.User.FirstName + " " + e.User.LastName).Trim()),
   Date = string.Format("{0:d}", e.Date)
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're using LINQ to Objects, I'd do this:

```
var query = from e in linq0
            select new
            {
                Id = e.Id,
                CommentText = e.CommentText,
                UserId = e.UserId,
                User = (e.User.FirstName + " " + e.User.LastName).Trim()),
                Date = e.Date.ToString("d")
            } into anon
            orderby anon.User descending
            select anon;
```

That way the string concatenation only has to be done once.

I don't know what that would do in LINQ to SQL though...

Comment: Great solution Jon. Just for cut-and-pasters like me, can you change `order by` to `orderby` in your code sample?

Comment: What if the member to sort by is unknown at runtime and comes as a string? ;)

Comment: @SuperJMN: Then it would be an entirely different question - but one that's been asked and answered many other times.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ouch, didn't know :( I have looked for that question and found nothing. Sorry.

Answer (score 7):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want to do this:

```
from e in linq0
order by (e.User.FirstName + " " + e.User.LastName).Trim()) descending 
select new
{
   Id = e.Id,
   CommentText = e.CommentText,
   UserId = e.UserId,
   User = (e.User.FirstName + " " + e.User.LastName).Trim()),
   Date = string.Format("{0:d}", e.Date)
}
```

Comment: +1 but please use String.Format() as seeing two string concatenations next to each other hurts my eyes and I know I'm not alone.

Comment: DrJokepu: It's not a problem here as it's not evaluated. It's parsed as an expression tree and sent as a SQL query to SQL Server to evaluate. In fact, it's not done twice as it is in LINQ2Objects. SQL Server will understand it and do it just once.

Comment: Mehrdad: Thanks for the clarification & apologies for being stupid.

Comment: By the way, `x + " " + y` should be faster than String.Format("{0} {1}", x, y). It'll evaluate to String.Concat(x, " ", y) which will allocate the buffer only once.

Answer (score 3):

Would this work, as a way of avoiding Jon's select...into?

```
from e in linq0
let comment = new
    {
       Id = e.Id,
       CommentText = e.CommentText,
       UserId = e.UserId,
       User = (e.User.FirstName + " " + e.User.LastName).Trim()),
       Date = string.Format("{0:d}", e.Date)
    }
orderby comment.User descending
select comment
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to get a necromancer badge for this answer, but I still think it's worth showing this snippet.

```
var records = await (from s in db.S
  join l in db.L on s.LId equals l.Id
  where (...)
  select new { S = s, Type = l.MyType }
  ).ToListAsync();

//Data is retrieved from database by now. 
//OrderBy below is LINQ to Objects, not LINQ to SQL

if (sortbyABC)
{
  //Sort A->B->C
  records.OrderBy(sl => sl.Type, new ABC());
}
else
{
   //Sort B->A->C
   records.OrderBy(sl => sl.Type, new BAC());
}
```

ABC and BAC implement `IComparer<MyType>`.