# how to sort an anonymous type without named columns

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Building from this question: [Trying to concatenate columns in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740246/trying-to-concatenate-columns-in-linq)

Now I want to sort:

```
var orderByIndexVal = Convert.ToInt32(Request["iSortCol_0"]);
var direction = Request["sSortDir_0"];

var gridInfo = 
    from leader in db.SchoolLdrAdminAccesses
        join emp in db.Employees
        on leader.ID equals emp.ID
        select new List<string> { leader.ID, emp.FirstName + " " + emp.LastName };

 return Json(new
        {
           sEcho = param.sEcho,
           iTotalRecords = gridInfo.Count(),
           iTotalDisplayRecords = gridInfo.Count(),
           aaData = gridInfo.ToArray()
         },
         JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

After reading this post:
[LINQ sorting anonymous types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414290/linq-sorting-anonymous-types)

My issue is that I don't have anything named in my `gridInfo`

**What I've tried so far:**

```
            if (direction == "asc")
            {
                gridInfo =  gridInfo.OrderBy(gi => gi[orderByIndexVal]);
            }
            else
            {
                gridInfo = gridInfo.OrderByDescending(gi => gi[orderByIndexVal]);
            }
```

**But I'm getting the following error:**

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

On the following block of code:

```
            return Json(new
            {
                sEcho = param.sEcho,
                iTotalRecords = gridInfo.Count(),
                iTotalDisplayRecords = gridInfo.Count(),
                aaData = gridInfo.ToArray()
            },
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but `gridInfo = gridInfo.OrderBy(...)` looks like it should do the trick. Did you try that?

Comment: @Jon I updated my question to show you what I've done and what I'm getting as an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to materialize the list, so the `order by` doesn't happen in the DB, but in .NET, after the concatenation takes place.

```
var gridInfo = (from leader in db.SchoolLdrAdminAccesses
        join emp in db.Employees
        on leader.ID equals emp.ID
        select new string[]{ leader.ID.ToString(), 
             emp.FirstName + " " + emp.LastName })
        .ToList();
```

Also note that using an array instead of a list uses less memory. Hope that helps.

Comment: when I add the orderby code I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't miss the ".ToList();" at the end?

Comment: When I use the syntax you suggested I get an error: The array type 'System.String[]' cannot be initialized in a query result. Consider using 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem

```
new List<string> { leader.ID, emp.FirstName + " " + emp.LastName };
```

the anonymous type you are selecting is two columns { Int, String } not a simple List

Just `Select new { leader.ID, emp.FirstName + " " + emp.LastName };`  the Select statement will make it an IEnumerable automatically, so you don;t need the List<> part

I am assuming leader.ID is an Int here (which may be wrong)

Comment: ID is an int, but by taking out the List<string> it is requiring me to name the firstName + lastName concatenation and I'm trying to avoid that because I'm converting it back out as JSON for a grid to consume and the grid doesn't like named JSON entries...

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but try new Dictionary<Int,String> in place of List<String> - at lease the datatypes should match